# Можно ли полноценно управлять VPS хостингом череp ssh?

Tags: хостинг

Можно ли полноценно управлять VPS хостингом череp ssh. Проблема в том, что на хостинге нет никакой панели управления.

Comment: Через ssh можно делать больше чем через "панель управления".

Comment: Хостинг - это (для владельца оного), чаще всего,  наличие доступа к MySQL через phpmyadmin, и доступ к ftp серверу, для "заливки" файлов. Управлять через ssh, вряд ли получится. Скорее всего провайдер запретил все остальные возможности.

Comment: Это что за бред?Причем тут провайдер? Понятия не путай!Какой к черту Хостинг, если ТС пишет про VPS???

Comment: "SSH — сетевой протокол прикладного уровня, позволяющий производить удалённое управление операционной системой", подробнее об этом описано в википедии. От себя скажу, что серверу работающему под управлением linux/unix систем, графическая оболочка вообще не нужна и все действия с сервером (настройка, обновление и прочее) производятся по ssh соединению. Без этих знаний нормальное администрирование *nix систем вообщем-то под сомнением. Настоятельно советую изучить данный протокол.

Comment: Хм, какой смысл в изучении этого протокола? "В чем сила брат (с)"Мне на самом деле никогда не было интересно как он работает, но я им пользуюсь, точнее через него пользуюсь. дело то не в протоколе а в знании команд и умении их применить ИМХО.

Comment: Изучение протокола в данном контексте, подразумевает изучение SSH (шифровонное безопасное соединение) и навыков работы с ним, из этого вытекает изучение команд управления системой и написание сценариев на bash например. Так как вопрос изначально задан человеком, вероятно не знакомым с работой через SSH вообще, то и ответ дан напраляющий в нужную сторону. Как работает SSH, знать должен каждый кто с ним работает, иначе бездумное прыгание по мосту, не ведея из чего он сделан, может привести к его обрыву.

Comment: Да нафига мне знать как работает этот протокол?Тоже самое зачем мне рыться в протоколе FTP и http?Они работают так как им нужно, ты ими только пользуешься, тебе не обязательно знать как они работают. Когда садишься за руль авто, многие и через 20 лет не знают как работает двигатель, но ездят же!ИМХО по-моему мнению ответ не в ту сторону.

Comment: @Вадим Бондарь, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: На любых курсах по вождению, вкратце в любом случае рассказывают и про двигатель и про основные неисправности автомобиля и даже заставляют сдавать первую помощь, так что Ваше утверждение не имеет под собой никакой обоснованности. То что у Вас отсутствует желание изучать что-то основательно, указывает лишь на тупик в Вашем интелектуальном развитии, а желание упереться рогами во что бы то ни стало, говорит о бараньей сущности и неспособности дать нормальный ответ человеку просящему помощи.

Comment: Ты бы со словами выбирал выражения.

Comment: В отличии от некоторых, я не ставлю никому минусы, не проанализировав прочитанное и полагаясь на эмоции.

Comment: @Вадим Бондарь, если Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз. ![alt text][1](взято из ответа @shaman888)  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/lPQEm.png

Answer (score 2):

SSH это полный доступ к серверу, еще бы был  IP-KVM так вообще это почти физически ты рядом с ним. Перезагружать и прочее можно, устанавливать ПО можно, настраивать систему и это можно.

Через SSH можно с сервером делать все что угодно.

Не просто полноценно управлять, а полностью!

Так что все можно, но раз задан такой вопрос, то не советую сразу браться за настройку своего сервера, много будешь наступать на грабли, т.к. нет опыта у тебя в настройке.

Читай про SSH, настройки связок, безопасность и прочее, и тогда настраивай сервак.

**//UPD**Единственный косяк VPS если он построен на OpenVZ, то нет SWAP раздела! А это громадный минус. т.е. по памяти нужно брать более мощный сервер, иначе повиснет нафиг :) Сталкивался с этим,  так что советую взять либо облачный, у которого есть возможность держать SWAP раздел, либо выделенный сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, ТС не из воздуха взял VPS, а кто-то, предположительно - хостинговая контора, предоставил Virtual Private Server (услуга, в рамках которой пользователю предоставляется так называемый Виртуальный выделенный сервер.)

По идее -  на ВИРТУАЛЬНЫЙ сервер права должны быть рутовые...

[VPS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPS).

[SSH](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH)

Еще веселее - [SSHFS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS).

Резюмируя:

Вадим Бондарь, ДА - можно! Причем, более полноценно, чем через любую(?) панель управления.